# Gitlab CI/CD running fine on local but not on gitlab

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml

I am trying to build a gitlab CI/CD pipeline on my java maven project. I tried all the stages on my local machine and they are passing successfully but when I try the same things on gitlab repo it is throwing error. I tried almost every solution and gone through numerous posts to resolve the errors but to no use. Here is my yml content:

```
image: maven:3.5-jdk-8

variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
   MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

include:
    - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/settings.xml

# Define stages
#   Stages group various steps into one block,
#   if any step fails, the entire stage fails
stages:
  - validate
  - compile
  - SonarQube
  - test
  
validate: 
  stage: validate
  script:
    - mvn validate

compile:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
  
sonarqube-check:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: SonarQube 
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
  script:
    - mvn sonar:sonar \ -Dsonar.projectKey=XX.XX.XXX.XXX \ -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX \ -Dsonar.login=XX.XX.XXX.XXX -X
  allow_failure: true

spotbugs-sast:
  variables:
    COMPILE: "false"
    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json


#spotbugs-sast:
#  variables:
#    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
    #FAIL_NEVER: 1

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test -B
```

The stage validate and compile are running fine but I am getting warnings in sonar check and spotbugs sast. The same is running fine on my local.
In the sonarqube check the error is:

```
Error resolving version for plugin ' -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX' from the repositories [local (/builds/XX.XX.XXX.XXX/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin ' -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX' from the repositories [local (/builds/XXXX/XXXXX/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

and for the spotbugs-sast warning the error is:

```
[FATA] [Find Security Bugs] ▶ lstat /root/.m2/repository: no such file or directory
```

I have spent numerous hours resolving this and waiting for the project to compile successfully with all the stages but every time I was disappointed. Please help. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Any help or suggestion will be useful. Thanks

Comment: Please can someone help ? I am working in weekend and this is critical to resolved by tomorrow.

Comment: The error shows that something that is required (sorry, non-java here) is not present on the runner. I think it runs locally, as you already have it in your computer. Though in the currently running image, it is not around, did you try installing/adding the missing component to the image your running in? Typically this happens in a `before_script`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am fairly new to yaml. What should I add under the before_script. I have tried multiple things. Any specifics I should be adding according to you based on the error messages. You can tell and I will try and get back with the results.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with yaml specific in my opinion. inb the before script you add a block of lines (starting with `-`, as you have in the script block) with the things you need to install/download for your project. Things you need, and you already have on your local machine

Comment: Can you guide me what should I add to my gitlab yaml file. My repo has a standard java maven project structure so in that sense what should I add under the before_script.

Comment: Sorry, I have 0 Java experience. But what you need to add, is the same as you need to run on a new computer to be able to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maven recognized the String  `-Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX` as a plugin/goal that it needs to resolve.
This is caused by the `\` in your script.

Instead of:
`mvn sonar:sonar \ -Dsonar.projectKey=XX.XX.XXX.XXX \ -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX \ -Dsonar.login=XX.XX.XXX.XXX -X`
try:
`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=XX.XX.XXX.XXX -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX -Dsonar.login=XX.XX.XXX.XXX -X`

I assume that you copied that command from a format like this:

```
mvn sonar:sonar \
 -Dsonar.projectKey=XX.XX.XXX.XXX \
 -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX \
 -Dsonar.login=XX.XX.XXX.XXX -X
```

In bash the `\` must be at the end of the line if the command contains a linebreak so it's recognized as one command.
But you need to remove it if you convert it to one line.

Comment: Now I am getting new error: Could not resolve dependencies for project project-name:jar:7.0.83: The following artifacts could not be resolved: :jar:4.0.4, :jar:1.0.0, :jar:4.3.9, :jar:1.27.4, :1.12.1, :jar:2.1 and Could not find artifact web:web-client:jar:4.0.4 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and there were names of so many jar files.

Comment: Here is the line error: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project name: Could not resolve dependencies for project

Comment: This is a bit hard to solve without knowing your project dependencies. The error is maven specific and has nothing to do with gitlab ci. I assume it is an internal project which uses internal jars that do not exist in maven central.  You can pick a random one and search for it on https://mvnrepository.com/ to see if it exists in a public repo. If it does not exist in maven central you need to add the repo to your pom.xml or a custom settingss.xml

Comment: oooh! wait a sec.... are the missing jars components that you build in the `compile` job?  If so, they won't be available in the `sonarqube-check` job. those 2 jobs can run on completly different runners without even knowing of each others existence. In that case you would need to specify the `target` folders as artifacts. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html Or alternatively you can combine the compile and the sunarqube-check job into one.

Comment: I added this: artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/
My java repo is a standard repository with dependencies and everything placed commonly where we usually store in a general project structure. This change is now throwing new errors:ERROR] /project/target/generated-code/src/com/filename.java:[35,2] cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class XmlAccessorType [ERROR] /project/target/generated-code/src/com/filename.java:[36,2] cannot find symbol

Comment: That error occurs when you use jdk11 on a jdk8 project that hasn't been migrated yet. You are using a jdk11 docker image in the sonarqube-check job, but a jdk 8 docker image for all other jobs. Either properly migrate your project to jdk 11, or use jdk 8 everywhere ;)

Comment: And can you also answer the second part where the security spotbug sast is failing with error: $ /analyzer run
[INFO] [Find Security Bugs]  ▶ GitLab Find Security Bugs analyzer v2.28.6
[INFO]  ▶ Detecting project
[INFO]   ▶ Found project in /builds/projectpath
[INFO]   ▶ Running analyzer
[DEBU] [Find Security Bugs] ▶ /bin/bash -c source /root/.bashrc && switch_to java 8
[INFO]   ▶ Found Maven project in /builds/projectname directory
[INFO] Found 1 analyzable projects.
[FATA]  lstat /root/.m2/repository: no such file or directory

Comment: well... does the folder exist? I don't know your project structure so it's really hard to help you with just bits and pieces of information. If it does exist, you might need to set the variable `MAVEN_REPO_PATH`  See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#available-cicd-variables for more information.

Comment: Here is how my sonar stage looks like: sonarqube-check:
 ` image: maven:3.5-jdk-8
  stage: SonarQube 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
  script:
    #- mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -U
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install rpm 
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=XXX -Dsonar.host.url=XXXX -Dsonar.login=XXXX -X
  allow_failure: true `still getting the same error. I appreciate for your time and effort. I think I am close.

Comment: And what is "the same error" ? We've discussed 4 different problems already :D

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the error. For security sast I changed it to use the variable: spotbugs-sast:
  variables:
    MAVEN_REPO_PATH: ./.m2/repository
    COMPILE: "false"
    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
    paths:
      - target/
It still throws error: lstat /root/.m2/repository: no such file or directory and for the sonar it is back to the earlier error where it could not resolve dependency. Please help. Its 3 am in the morning here and I need to finish this. Really grateful for your help.

Comment: My issue is still not resolved. Can you help ?